# Interdisciplinary PhDs?

Tags: phd, united-states, interdisciplinary

Is there such a thing as an interdisciplinary PhD, where the student chooses the fields, courses, etc.? If so, which U.S. universities offer such a thing?

Comment: Almost every PhD program allows students to choose their own electives, and if you Google "interdisciplinary PhD" you will get many results, since this word became very fashionable a few decades ago.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a while I was a graduate student in the math department of Portland State University. At Portland State, the Ph.D. program in math *requires* students to have an "allied area" (field of study other than mathematics). The student's thesis must be related to this allied area, the student must take about 25% percent of their courses in the allied area, and the student must pass a qualifying exam in the allied area. Thus the whole program is designed to be interdisciplinary from the get-go.

(Side note: The actual name of degree is "Ph.D. in Mathematical Sciences", and it definitely differs from the traditional math Ph.D.)

Answer (score 3):

In general, every Ph.D. is officially within some formal department, or other program, and a Ph.D. student will need to do at least whatever courses that program requires.  Some such programs, however, are extremely interdisciplinary by their nature: some nice examples are MIT's [Engineering Systems Division](http://esd.mit.edu/) and [Media Lab](http://media.mit.edu/), where participants have the opportunity to take a wide variety of different courses connected to different disciplines.  Every program has some (often relatively loose) expectations about what a student will do, however, so you're unlikely to find anything where you just get to pick whatever you feel like.

Beyond a certain point, however, a Ph.D. is not about coursework.  Once you start to focus on your research, then you can do anything that you and your advisor agree is appropriate...